# FFmpeg First 2 Seconds of Video Not Showing

Tags: image, audio, video, ffmpeg, mp4

[This code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34827593/1303123) works fine for some audio files (makes a slideshow of JPG pictures with a PNG watermark and MP3 audio, while maintaining aspect ratio) but for [this audio file](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g4e19934543580114999775292e9f64402b60413cc), the pictures are not showing for the first two seconds or so of the video:

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 1/12 -i "media/%03d.jpg" -i "media/audio.mp3" -loop 1 -i "media/watermark.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw*min(3840/iw\,2160/ih):ih*min(3840/iw\,2160/ih), pad=3840:2160:(3840-iw)/2:(2160-ih)/2[ss]; [ss][2:v] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:shortest=1[out]" -map "[out]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -r 24 -preset veryfast -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -map_metadata -1 "media/video.mkv" -report`

I tried converting the audio into different formats of MP3, tried changing bitrates, changed audio to stereo, and even tried converting it to a WAV. None of these things worked.

Here are [the report results](https://jsfiddle.net/oLoemncL/) for when I run this command.

If it makes a difference, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and FFmpeg version N-77455-g4707497 (latest version).

Comment: Try with `-fflags +genpts`  as an output option.

Comment: @Mulvya, I get the same result. Here is [the report](https://jsfiddle.net/oLoemncL/1/) when run with `-fflags +genpts`.

Comment: Take the audio out of the equation. Remove `-i "media/audio.mp3"`, `-map 1:a` and `-c:a copy`

Comment: @Mulvya, when I took these things out, [there is an error](https://jsfiddle.net/oLoemncL/2/) which prevents the video from being saved.

Comment: Sorry. Now that the audio is out, the overlay inputs are `[ss][1:v]`

Comment: @Mulvya, now it saves a non-working video. Here is [the report](https://jsfiddle.net/oLoemncL/3/).

Comment: Run `ffprobe media/video.mkv -report` and `ffprobe -show_packets media/video.mkv > frames.txt` and paste those files.

Comment: @Mulvya, here are [the results of those commands](https://jsfiddle.net/oLoemncL/4/).

Comment: Ok, add the audio back in, and add `fps=24` before the first `[ss]`

Comment: @Mulvya, thanks! That works. If you'd please add this as an answer so I can mark it as correct. Do you have any tips as to how an FFmpeg beginner like myself can learn all about FFmpeg?

Comment: Consult the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html) and similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command should work, but I consider this bizarre behaviour as FFmpeg should be automatically padding frames as per output spec

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 1/12 -i "media/%03d.jpg" -i "media/audio.mp3" -loop 1 -i "media/watermark.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw*min(3840/iw\,2160/ih):ih*min(3840/iw\,2160/ih), pad=3840:2160:(3840-iw)/2:(2160-ih)/2,fps=24[ss]; [ss][2:v] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:shortest=1[out]" -map "[out]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -r 24 -preset veryfast -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -map_metadata -1 "media/video.mkv"
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Mine was a simpler usecase. I just wanted to create an mp4 out of a few images. `ffmpeg -r 1/10 -y -framerate 1/12 -i file_%d.png -c:v libx264 -r 24 -preset veryfast -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" video.mp4` worked for me. The `pad` is for the error `width not divisible by 2 (2481x3508)`.